# using 2 different styles in one form in android using Delphi10.1

Tags: android, delphi, styles, delphi-10.1-berlin

is it possible to use 2 diffrant styles in one android form?, i'm using copper style for the whole form and i want to use Jet style for the speedButton,i dont see ant property to set that

Comment: AFAIK. you can have only one style per app.

Comment: @UweRaabe Couldn't you just create another Style manager and connect certain components to that Style manager instead of the default one?

Comment: @SilverWarior, I don't think so. TStyleManager has only class methods and is never instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One style usually refer to one Image file with all style graphics (icons etc). So if you want to use SpeedButton from another style - you need to use Photoshop or any Image editor: Save style images of 2 styles, open images in PS, copy speedbutton part from Jet style image, paste it into your current style image file (usually 3 bitmaps, for 3 scales).

For Jet speedbutton main Bitmap is "Android Jetstyle.png" - search it in styles. Save this bitmap as png so you can open it in ImageEditor and copy some part to your style image. Then find Speedbuttonstyle in styles, check object with name **background** - look at NormalLink, PressedLink, HotLink images.

All this will take some time.